# error: Grunt :: [BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "../js/all.min.js" as it exceeds the max of "500KB". in Sail.js?

Tags: sails.js, babeljs, production-environment, font-awesome-5

Why am I getting

`error: Grunt :: [BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of ".tmp/public/js/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.min.js" as it exceeds the max of "500KB".`

in **Sail.js** app at **production** mode? Please suggest me how to fix it?

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjBNI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many research I found that earlier babel compress max size was : 100kb. Now they have increased it to max : 500kb. But still I have that error, to fix it we have to insert a small code snippet.

In Sails JS App v.1.x - Goto

> `task->config->babel.js`

and insert this code : **compact: false**
inside :

```
dist: {
    options: {
        presets: [require('sails-hook-grunt/accessible/babel-preset-env')],
        compact: false
    },
    ...
    ....
}
```